# QListViewModel UI

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write a QListView model and link it to my main UI (from Qt Designer)

here's my main function:

```
#include "notepad.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Notepad w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and here's my main class Notepad:

```
Notepad::Notepad(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Notepad)
{
/* some other setup code */
ui->setupUi(this);

FileViewModel fileModel(files, 0);
ui->listView->setModel(&fileModel);
ui->listView->show();
}
```

However, the listView doesn't seem to be displaying any elements, whereas I've provided basic functionality in my model.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: The model ceases to exist as soon as the constructor is done with. This is a basic C++ mistake, in the typo category. The answer won't help anyone else. Thus it's offtopic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FileViewModel *fileModel = new FileViewModel(files, 0);
ui->listView->setModel(fileModel);
```